# show posts names and links in the sidebar list as categories child

Tags: categories, posts, sidebar

i'm using this plugin to show an exapandable/collapsible widget-menu in my sidebar.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/folding-category-widget
it works very well!

the question, not directly connected with this plugin, is: how can i also show in the list, all posts related to a category (title + a href)?

for example:

```
category A 
         post1
         post2

category B
         post3
         post4

category C
         post5
```

thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the simplest way I can think of is something like this...

```
<ul class="categories">
<?php
    $categories = get_categories(); //can add parameters here to swtich the order, etc;
    if(!empty(categories)):
        foreach($categories as $i => $category):
?>

<li class="category">
    <span><?php echo $category->name ?></span>

        <?php

        query_posts('posts_per_page=-1&cat=' . $category->term_id);
        if ( have_posts() ) :
        ?>
        <ul class="posts">
        <?php
             while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); //we make a loop for each category, 
        ?>
            <li class="post">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a>
            </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</li>
        <?php endforeach; endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Warning: this is untested code, but it should work just fine. (Just add it to your sidebar.php file or wherever you generate your sidebar.)

Comment: Plus it ought to be said that as the number of categories increase, your going to start racking up a fair few database queries!

Comment: That's true. Another way to do this would be to just get all the posts and all the cateogries, and for each category, go through the posts array and include them if thery're in that certain category. That would be more database efficient, but you still have to parse the array.

Comment: I'm using this to show posts without categories in my sidebar. Just worked! Tks!